# SQL UPDATE in python string substitution partially works

Tags: python-3.x, string, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 with python3 to build a rudimentary database system. I've create a database now I want to know how to update it. The following function works and gives the desired output.

```
def update_db(table_name,column_name):
    con = db_connect()
    cur = con.cursor()
    id_column  ='first_name'
    update_sql = """ UPDATE {}  SET {} = 'hi' where {} = "ID_0-1" """.format(table_name, column_name, id_column)
    cur.execute(update_sql)
    con.commit()
```

However, if I try to generalise the update_sql statement as such:

```
def update_db(table_name,column_name):
    con = db_connect()
    cur = con.cursor()
    id_column  ='first_name'
    value = 'hi'
    id_value = "ID_0-1"
    update_sql = """ UPDATE {}  SET {} = {} where {} = {} """.format(table_name, column_name, value, id_column, id_value)
    cur.execute(update_sql)
    con.commit()
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database_intialisation.py", line 97, in <module>
    fill_column(table_name, column_name)
  File "database_intialisation.py", line 77, in fill_column
    cur.execute(update_sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: hi
```

I've also tried %s string substitution method and it yields similar results.

Comment: Quote at `hi`, you need to quote the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change sql string to:

```
""" UPDATE {}  SET {} = '{}' where {} = '{}' """
```

Note: this approach have many problem and you should use `parameterized query`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, using the `?` placeholder:

```
update_sql = """ UPDATE {}  SET {} = ? where {} = ? """.format(table_name, column_name, id_column)
cur.execute(update_sql, (value, id_value))
```

Your `'hi'` is inserted into statement as `hi` and it is trying to set the value of your column to the value the would be in column `hi`.